Possible to install Tailscale on a Bitaxe?
Does anyone know how to install Tailscale on a Bitaxe Gamma? I'd like to remotely log into my network and check the status of the Bitaxe outside of my home network. Tailscale is great for this, but not sure how to get into the Terminal on the Bitaxe box. And not sure if I run the Linux commands to install Tailscale, whether this would not break the Bitaxe.
Or any other thoughts on how to access outside the network (maybe via Tor)?

See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/123880/13866
